# Proving logical consequence from sequence (fast)

Tags: logic

Given a sequence such as a |= c, I know you can determine if it is a logical consequence by solving for a->c.

However if I am given something along the lines of this given the sequence: k -> n or u, u -> not k |= not u.

Or to simplify: a,b |= c.

My question is which of the following below is correct to solve for logical consequence.

1. a and b -> c
2. a or b -> c

I am fairly certain there is an or relationship (the second one is right), but I can't quite explain why.

Comment: What is "a sequence such as a := c" ?

Comment: Sorry I meant "|=", I will fix it in the post.

Comment: Very far from clear... You want to prove: $k \to n \lor u, u \to \lnot k \vDash \lnot u$. You cannot, because it is not true. Consider a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(u)=$ TRUE, $v(k)=$ FALSE:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; $A \vDash C \text { iff } \vDash A \to C$.

But $A, B \vDash C \text { iff } \vDash (A \land B) \to C \text { iff } \vDash A \to (B \to C)$.

See [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence). The LHS means that:

> it is not the case that $C$ is FALSE and $A$ and $B$ are TRUE.